# Lossy audio/video/image formats and data loss

Tags: audio, video, images, lossless

I once heard that if you store music/videos/images in lossy formats, the quality gradually degrades over time.

> The difference in perception is not the only reason to store music in FLAC. FLAC uses lossless compression, while MP3 uses lossy compression. From this it turns out that for every year that MP3 is stored on disk, the files will lose approximately 12 kilobits of bitrate if you have SATA. On IDE there will be as much as 15 kilobits, but on SCSI only 7 kilobits, due to the high-speed rotation density. And you have no idea how bad things are for CDs and other optical media. I started collecting MP3s in 2001, and if you listen to the tracks I downloaded back then, even the tracks saved at 320kbps sound disgusting. The bass is terrible, the mids... better not even start! Many disks have since degraded to 32 or even 16kb/s. Meanwhile, FLAC rips from that era still sound great, even if they were not stored in suitable conditions - a cool, dry place. Seriously, use FLAC, even if you don't hear the difference now, in a couple of years you'll be glad you did.

Is it really so?

Comment: Have you collect that quotation from some audiophile's forum, perhaps? From the same people promoting "CD demagnetizers" and USD900+ audio cables, right? Asking because I never ever read such a bunch of nonsense in a single paragraph before.

Comment: Oh please, post the link to this pearl of wisdom...

Comment: @ChanganAuto This is a Russian Linux forum, here is the link: https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/talks/17512190?cid=17512617

Comment: @ChanganAuto https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mH4v8b1tGSQ & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-QxLAxwxkM

Comment: "the files will lose approximately 12 kilobits of bitrate if you have SATA." Is a complete load of mindless idiocy that has no grounding in reality. This sounds like someone who heard the term "bit rot", which is a real thing to do with electromagnetic storage decay, and applied it to files themselves at an insanely magnified rate. Bit rot would largely cause the disk to report uncorrectable errors (due to on disk CRC checking) and fail to read a data rather than silently degrading a file. Any failure or degredation in the magnetic media would be trivial to detect.

Comment: @Gantendo Thanks for the videos but I already watched them while laughing all the way. Indeed, it was because of those Techmoan videos I knew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the quality gradually degrades over time.

No, that's utter nonsense. Or rather, the tone of the quoted post sounds like it's *mocking* the usual audiophile discussions (especially the kind that tries to sell you "high-grade Ethernet cables for warmer sound").

Quality may degrade over *re-encodings,* e.g. if you have an MP3 that is then converted to an AAC/M4A it will lose information (it will *never improve* the quality even if you're converting to a "better" format); but that only happens due to explicit conversion steps and not something that happens over time.

---

There's a *little* truth in the quote, however: encoding algorithms for certain formats have improved over time, and an "128 kbps" MP3 encoded using software available in 2024 is likely to sound better than an "128 kbps" MP3 encoded using software from 2001 – not because the latter has degraded over time, but because the old encoding process was bad to begin with.

(I've heard this mentioned specifically about the MP3 encoder that used to be built-in to Windows 98, and about the AAC encoder(s) found in FFmpeg; the built-in AAC codec found in earlier versions was allegedly garbage and everyone said "use fdk-aac" before it was finally fixed.)

(And of course a 20-year-old JPEG that went through fifteen different forums and social platforms, each of which insists on JPEG-compressing it again, will have the "well-worn" look to it after just 4-5 recompressions.)

Comment: It would be trivial to check too, just run a checksum on the file itself to see if it got changed.

Comment: There is [bitrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_degradation)